# How to do POST-INSTALLATION after conda install opencv

Tags: opencv, conda

After I installed opencv in conda environment, I activate myenv.

python3 is then used from myenv-python3, but opencv is still using the system env-opencv, why this happened? Did I forget to do any POST-INSTALLATION, like adding PATH or modify PKG-CONFIG?

command for building conda virtual env:

conda env create -n myenv -f env.yml

**cv2.so is already there, the libopencv* files are also there, the installation should be OK.** It seems like PATH or something is the problem.

```
name: cv320_tf
channels:
- menpo
- defaults
dependencies:
- cairo=1.14.8=0
- certifi=2016.2.28=py35_0
- cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
- dbus=1.10.20=0
- expat=2.1.0=0
- fontconfig=2.12.1=3
- freetype=2.5.5=2
- glib=2.50.2=1
- gst-plugins-base=1.8.0=0
- gstreamer=1.8.0=0
- harfbuzz=0.9.39=2
- hdf5=1.8.17=2
- icu=54.1=0
- jbig=2.1=0
- jpeg=9b=0
- libffi=3.2.1=1
- libgcc=5.2.0=0
- libgfortran=3.0.0=1
- libiconv=1.14=0
- libpng=1.6.30=1
- libtiff=4.0.6=3
- libxcb=1.12=1
- libxml2=2.9.4=0
- matplotlib=2.0.2=np111py35_0
- mkl=2017.0.3=0
- numpy=1.11.3=py35_0
- openssl=1.0.2l=0
- pandas=0.20.1=np111py35_0
- patsy=0.4.1=py35_0
- pcre=8.39=1
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- pixman=0.34.0=0
- pyparsing=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
- python=3.5.4=0
- python-dateutil=2.6.1=py35_0
- pytz=2017.2=py35_0
- qt=5.6.2=5
- readline=6.2=2
- scipy=0.19.0=np111py35_0
- seaborn=0.8=py35_0
- setuptools=36.4.0=py35_1
- sip=4.18=py35_0
- six=1.10.0=py35_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- statsmodels=0.8.0=np111py35_0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- xz=5.2.3=0
- zlib=1.2.11=0
- opencv3=3.2.0=np111py35_0
- pip:
  - bleach==1.5.0
  - enum34==1.1.6
  - html5lib==0.9999999
  - markdown==2.6.11
  - protobuf==3.5.1
  - tensorflow==1.4.1
  - tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0
  - werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Comment: Could you show the command you used to install `opencv`? Screen shot would be easier to let the reviewer what you have exactly done.

Comment: There is no explicit command to install it. I used yml file to create a new environment once. The command is conda env create -n myenv -f env.yml, that's all. In yml file, only packages with version and built tools are mentioned, nothing else. The installation seems good, but I find that everytime I have to first go into virtual env site-packages folder, otherwise import cv2 can not find it. Except one thing, my virtual environment's name is myenv, but inside yml file the name is cv320_tf. I wonder whether this will cause issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below steps

1. Uninstall existing opencv
2. Install opencv inside the conda environment using the command "**conda install opencv**"

Comment: So this is really the only way to do this? Ehhh....So basically when we want different versions of OpenCV or whatever, install them in virtual and never install in system?

Comment: It would be better if you install the dependencies in your conda environment to avoid version mismatch with the default system packages